# Beautiful soup body tags damaged

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I would like to display the contents of the webpage: http://movie.webindia123.com/movie/showtimes/asp/search_result.asp?language=57&district_name=42&city_name=118 in tabular manner but when I use the soup the body tag seems to be damaged with space between each characters. The source code I used:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="http://movie.webindia123.com/movie/showtimes/asp/search_result.asp?language=57&district_name=42&city_name=118"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print soup

for hit in soup.findAll(attrs={'class' :'section group'}):
   text=hit
   print text.get_text()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "space between each characters" - can you provide an example?

Comment: r e g i o n a l   m o v i e s   ,   r e v i e w ,   p r e v i e w ,   w a l l   p a p e r ,   s t i l l ,   t r a i l e r s ,   t a m i l ,   t e l e g u ,   m a l a y a l a m ,  b o d y   b g c o l o r = " # F F F F F F " &gt;

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that helps. Where in the HTML do you see this text?

Comment: The output exceeds the wordlimit for the comment textfield so can't post that

Answer (score 0):

Please use the JSON module to access the web document after that parse the document using beautiful soup.
A snippet of the code is give below:

```
        #Get HTML
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
browser = mechanize.Browser()
cj = mechanize.LWPCookieJar()
browser.set_cookiejar(cj)
#browser = mechanize.OpenerFactory().build_opener(mechanize.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
#request = mechanize.Request(url)
response = browser.open(url)
html = response.read()
browser.select_form(name="trace")
browser["mobilenumber"] = str(site)
browser.submit()
html=browser.response().read()
#print browser.geturl() 
#print html
#Parse HTML with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
```